# TypeError: Class extends value undefined. My Class extension not working

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a new `Button` class that extends from the parent `Component` class. Please pay attention to the very first line, namely how I import the `Component` class.

Button.ts:

```
import * as Classes from "../../classes/index";
import * as CmpInterfaces from '../../interfaces/Components/index';
import * as Types from '../../Types';

class Button extends Classes.Component implements CmpInterfaces.Button
{
    public type: Types.ButtonType = 'contained';

    /**
     * @param properties
     */
    constructor(properties: CmpInterfaces.Button) {
        super(properties);
        this.bind();
    }
}

export default Button;
```

The index.ts file

```
import * as Classes from "../../classes/index";
```

contains the following code:

```
export { default as Component } from '../../classes/Component';
export * from '../../classes/Component';
```

It looks good, but at compile time I get an error:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

However, if I import the `Component` class directly, it doesn't throw any errors:

```
// import * as Classes from "../../classes/index";
import Component from '../classes/Component';

import * as CmpInterfaces from '../../interfaces/Components/index';
import * as Types from '../../Types';

// `extends Classes.Component` changed to => `extends Component`
class Button extends Component implements CmpInterfaces.Button
{
    public type: Types.ButtonType = 'contained';

    /**
     * @param properties
     */
    public constructor(properties: CmpInterfaces.Button)
    {
        super(properties);
        this.bind();
    }
}

export default Button;
```

I don't quite understand why this error occurs and why it doesn't work with interfaces...